# Will making updates to "externally_connectable" in the manifest.json file require that users accept new permissions?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest.json

Currently, my Chrome Extension doesn't use the "externally_connectable" key in the manifest.json file. However, it's something that needs to be added in an upcoming update. The extension already has permissions/host permissions for (let's say) "https://google.com/*".

When an extension adds new permissions, it asks the user if they are willing to accept the new permissions as soon as the update reaches them.

Will adding "https://google.com/*" to "externally_connectable" show the same alert to users currently using the extension as if it were adding a new permission, or will it not do so because the extension already has access to the website?

According to previous experience, users are alerted when "externally_connectable" is updated, but that was when the website wasn't already included in permissions. I'm not sure whether or not this is still the case if the extension already uses the website.

Comment: Only permissions with warnings cause a prompt, and externally_connectable doesn't have it.